# Is it possible to apply gradient color in a bitmap image a particular section?

Tags: android, gradient, android-bitmap

Using **flood fill** algorithm for one color work very fine but using gradient color can't apply .

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get what you mean so do you have anything that i can take a look at?

Comment: i mean  this kinds of image gradient color apply particular section.  https://www.google.com/search?q=color+book+image&tbm=isch&imgil=8U9ATvRwOV59LM%253A%253B8idVxNOaKFJdKM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.free-coloring-pages.com%25252Feaster%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=8U9ATvRwOV59LM%253A%252C8idVxNOaKFJdKM%252C_&usg=__b5wCC-cz5efTnW1nCuirvJgCuZs%3D&biw=1920&bih=947&ved=0ahUKEwiqgPjHkbzQAhXJPo8KHULlDdgQyjcIOQ&ei=hhs0WKqlEsn9vATCyrfADQ